# device /dev/ttyusb0 lock failed: operation not permitted

Tags: shell, terminal, emulation

I was playing around with a router earlier this evening using minicom and I must not have closed it cleanly. Here is the error message that I get when I try to open minicom:

```
device /dev/ttyusb0 lock failed: operation not permitted
```

I have two questions, 1) how would I go about getting out of this state, and 2) how do I exit minicom cleanly so that I can avoid this happening again.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found I was able to fix the situation on my CentOS box by running `minicom -S <device> -o` and the do the normal exit key sequence (CTRL-a, x).

In your situation it would have been

`sudo minicom -S ttyusb0 -o`

This cleared the lock files minicom had placed in /var/lock/

Good luck
Ash

Comment: "This cleared the lock files..." This didn't work, but manually deleting these lock files did. heh.

Comment: I manually deleted the `/var/lock/LCK..ttyUSB0` file and it works now.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar issue with using `gtkterm` from a remote terminal.  I had shutdown the terminal without explicitly terminating `gtkterm`.  The result was that subsequent gtkterm sessions gave me the error:

`Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is locked.`

Checking the process list via `ps` did not show any `gtkterm` processes still running.

I corrected this by simply deleting `/run/lock/LCK..ttyUSB0`.  After doing that, gtkterm was able to open ttyUSB0 successfully.

Answer (score 3):

1. [root@edge-tc lock]# minicom'
2. Device /dev/ttyUSB0 lock failed: Operation not permitted.'
3. Solution:'
4. Check the process which have locked and kill the process'
5. [root@edge-tc lock]# fuser /dev/ttyUSB0'
6. `/dev/ttyUSB0:        18328`
7. [root@edge-tc lock]# kill -9 18328
8. [root@edge-tc lock]#'
9. [root@edge-tc lock]#'
10. [root@edge-tc lock]# minicom'
11. Welcome to minicom 2.1'

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to use [lockdev](https://linux.die.net/man/3/lockdev). This manages the lock files on a per-device basis in `/run/lock/lockdev/` (at least under CentOS 7.x).

`lockdev <device>` can be used without being root, and returns non-zero if the device has already been locked, in which case it can be unlocked with `lockdev -u <device>`.

This is apparently obsolete these days, but `minicom` (at least as of version 2.6.2) still uses it.